# Organize excel columns together

Tags: excel

I have three excel spreadsheets and I don't how to do anything with excel. I need to find a way to associate IDs from one column to another column.

I have a column called "Display Name" and I have 2 columns in another worksheet called "IDs" and "Display name".

I want to compare the "Display names" from the first spreadsheet to the "Display names" on the second spreadsheet. I then I want to pull all the ids and match them based on there name. I have over 1000 and don't want to do this manually.

I copied the IDs to the first worksheet. Here is a picture of what I am trying to do:
[image]

Any ideas or links to help me get started would be awesome. I literally don't know anything about excel. I tried vlookups but I kept getting either a name error or a ref error.

Thanks for your time,

Comment: `VLOOKUP()`, `INDEX()/MATCH()` should work for you.

Comment: I tried vlookup multiple times and that didn't work. I also mentioned that in the main post as well. Every single time it kept giving a #name or #ref error even though I was follow this video exactly as instructed: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODZfwD39gGE

I will try the index/match and update the post

Comment: I feel like I am half way there. I was able to do `match()` which gave me a numbered result back which is the same row of where I want my data from. I think I will be able to get this done soon with some more research. thanks for the starting point @Harun24HR

Comment: Give a try my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `INDEX()/MATCH()` like-

```
=INDEX(O:O,MATCH(A2,P:P,0))
```

Comment: This is literally the coolest thing I have ever seen. I don't know anything on excel and appreciate you taking the time to present an answer to this.